# How do I make styling and fonts work on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I've got a node project with a create-react-app project in a folder called client.

It's setup on Heroku and deploys and works (functionaly) using git push heroku master but none of the styling is active and it's using the wrong fonts.

It all works on localhost.

In the project package.json I have

```
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
```

and in client package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Cannot find anything wrong in Heroku setup or logs, or any documentation, at a bit of a loss where to start even looking

Comment: I'd start by looking in your browser's devtools. Are some resources not being found (HTTP 404)? Are there other errors in the console, or in the network tab? Based on what you've shared so far it's very unlikely that we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Anything I can share that would be more illuminating? There's no errors in the console

Comment: You see your style files loading successfully in the network tab?

Comment: Theres no errors in the network tab, all 200 or 304 if loaded again. Should I see some style specific files loading? I don't see anything obvious, a couple of chunk.js files? And thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: OK, so I think it might just be the css file that is not getting built, loaded, used, an page that is pure react styling works OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included the css file in index.html